# Is there an option to know when somebody (especially author of the post) does something after my comment?

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface, notifications

Yes I do realize that the comments are primarily meant to introduce improvements in the post being commented on. And also that if any subsequent commenters want my feedback, they will @ me explicitly. But even if this is not done, I would prefer to know about subsequent activity around the post which I commented on. Maybe the @ has been forgotten, or maybe there are some other reasons for me to react to further developments. I gather right now the only way is to revisit my comments via the [activity tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=activity&sort=comments). Could I be notified when any kind of activity of mine has been followed by some other activity?

Besides, in some (maybe indirect) way my comments may result in, say, edits of the post without me being notified. Could that be detected somehow too?

Comment: I removerd the [meta-tag:feature-request] It should only be used for making a *precise* suggestion for a new feature. Instead, I added [meta-tag:discussion] since beyond getting information about the current situation you seem to be interested in *discussing* how (what exactly) could/should be done.  (If you actually want this to be a feature request you should be more precise; for example, what does "any kind of activity" mean?)

Comment: @quid OK thanks, I will think about it. If I'll manage to come up with a precise formulation I will edit the post accordingly.

Comment: You mean something like a “follow” feature — not the “favourite” star — so that any changes to that question are mentioned in your inbox. I can see the use of such a feature.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't know, how to write your name in  a comment; so maybe using a latinized name would result in more @ before it.

Comment: @ManfredWeis You can use the autocomplete menu appearing when you type '@'. Select the username via arrow keys and insert via tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a few months, [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232), including MathOverflow. It does require you to click the 'follow' link underneath a post.

> After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices.

There's a list of followed posts in your [profile](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=following).

Comment: Great! Exactly what I wanted.